# Highcharts master detail chart with irregular time intervals

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to do a cleaner version of master detail chart which gets driven only by a array of (epochtime, value) pairs like one here : http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/three-series-1000-points.js

Where time can be at irregular intervals and nothing is hardcoded. In the current version so much is hard coded from start time to end time to interval.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unforuantely it is availavle only in the highstock

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal

You can load data dynamically, like on our examples: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/

Reletaed article about it: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing/